# Solving polynomial-exponential equations

Tags: calculus

How do I solve for the roots of $4^x - 7x + 2 = 0$? I think you use a Lambert W function, and I know that there are two roots but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: In general, the equation [$p^x=ax+b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1), where $p>0$, $p\neq 1$ and $a\neq 0$ can be solved using the substitution $-t=x+\dfrac{b}{a}$, giving a solution in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: Formatting suggestion: put a dollar sign at the beginning and end of your equation to put your equation in math mode.

Comment: $$x \approx 0.625923,x \approx 1.60181$$

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by projectilemotion, your equation can be solved in terms of the Lambert W function.

Doing so, rewriting the equation 
\begin{align*}
e^{x \ln 4} &= 7x - 2\\
\Rightarrow (7x - 2) e^{-x \ln 4} &= 1\\
\Rightarrow \left (x - \frac{2}{7} \right ) e^{-x \ln 4} &= \frac{1}{7}\\
\Rightarrow - \ln 4 \left (x - \frac{2}{7} \right ) e^{-x \ln 4} &= - \frac{\ln 4}{7}\\
\Rightarrow \left (-x \ln 4 + \frac{2}{7} \ln 4 \right ) e^{- x \ln 4 + \frac{2}{7} \ln 4} &= - \frac{2 \ln 2}{7} e^{\frac{2}{7} \ln 4},
\end{align*}
on solving, in terms of the Lambert W function, we have
$$-x \ln 4 + \frac{2}{7} \ln 4 = \text{W}_\nu \left (-\frac{2 \ln 2}{7} e^{\frac{4 \ln 2}{7}} \right ),$$
or
$$x = \frac{2}{7} - \frac{1}{2 \ln 2} \text{W}_\nu \left (-\frac{2 \ln 2}{7} e^{\frac{4 \ln 2}{7}} \right ).$$
Here $\nu$ denotes the branch of the Lambert W function.

As the argument appearing in the Lambert W function lies between $-1/e \leqslant x < 0$ there will be two real solutions. The first is given by the principal branch $\text{W}_0 (x)$ of the Lambert W function while the second is given by the secondary real branch $\text{W}_{-1} (x)$ of the Lambert W function.

Thus
$$x = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{7} - \dfrac{1}{2 \ln 2} \text{W}_0 \left (-\dfrac{2 \ln 2}{7} e^{\frac{4 \ln 2}{7}} \right )\\
\dfrac{2}{7} - \dfrac{1}{2 \ln 2} \text{W}_{-1} \left (-\dfrac{2 \ln 2}{7} e^{\frac{4 \ln 2}{7}} \right ).
\end{cases}$$